# При прогрузке и появлении рекламного баннера падает FPS

Tags: java, android, admob

Выглядит всё примерно так:
https://youtu.be/mt2H_gm7n6c

В `layout` блок рекламы прописываю вот так:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Потом просто нахожу его в методе onCreate второй активности и гружу рекламу:

```
AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("2792B4EC7E5401859768008706660001").build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Лаги, в виде потери кадров и замедления анимации, замечены на устройствах с API>=21, то есть новее, чем Android Marshmallow. Использую последние библиотеки и CompileSDK.

Реклама - AdMob из библиотеки `com.google.android.gms.ads`.

Вопрос следующий: почему лагает, и как это исправить?

Comment: Не надо помещать его в AsyncTask и все. Там итак все асинхронно по идее

Comment: mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); Она же итак visible? Что значит лагает? В чем проявляется

Comment: А, ну ясно, ну раз лагает значит лагает и так надо, что тут вам еще ответить если даже не понятно чего вы хотите.... Сначала пишете про асинк таск потом про лагает. Извиняюсь. Я когда читаю про асинк таск, вспоминается где то 2014 год

Comment: По ссылке вижу что как минимум кривая разметка которая наслаивает элементы друг на друга. Как по мне так это уже лаг в разметке или кривой код. Если добавить сюда кучу левых и ненужных аттрибутов типа visible итд то не удивительно что там что то лагает. Если же более по существу, то попробуйте рекламу предзагружать в классе Application и во втором активити показывать. Так как лаги именно из за этого. В сети есть куча примеров на эту тему. Ну и мы как минимум не знакомы что бы тут тыкать как бэ

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает термин "лагает"?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Лаг (от англ. lag, [læɡ] — «запаздывание», «задержка») — задержка в работе компьютерного приложения, когда оно не реагирует на пользовательский ввод вовремя. Производное от него «лагать» широко используются пользователями интернета для обозначения задержек в работе различных интернет-сервисов, онлайн-игр. Также геймеры используют слово «лаг» применительно к задержкам самой программы. Часто встречается в сетевых играх. С технической точки зрения представляет собой проявление влияния латентности операций передачи и обработки данных на качество работы системы реального времени.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Эта известная проблема, которая много раз обсуждалась в сети, достаточно поискать по словам "admob fps drop" и тому подобным.

Корень проблемы здесь, скорее всего, в том, что для запуска AdMob требуются существенные ресурсы, из-за чего анимация начинает буксовать. В качестве одного решения можно показывать рекламу с некоторой задержкой:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
          mAdView.loadAd(bannerRequest);
     }
}, 2000);
```

[Отчёт о таком решении](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232228/93540) похожей проблемы. [И ещё один.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683378/93540)

Можно сделать задержку не фиксированную, а привязать её к действиям пользователя. Например, начинать загружать рекламу через мгновение после того как пользователь перестал прокручивать экран.

Другим решением предлагается [отключать ускорение графики для рекламы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695126/93540), манипулируя [свойством `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#view-level).

```java
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        runOnWebView(mAdView, new WebViewAction() {
            @Override
            public void run(WebView view) {
                // the most important part is here
                view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Аналогично можно выключить ускорение для какой-то Activity:

```xml
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

Понятно что такое действие может категорически негативно сказаться на сроке службы батареи при использовании вашего приложения, но если проблема будет решена, то может быть оно того стоит? Решать вам.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Должен отметить, что лаги возникают и без анимации: если внимательно скроллить активность (просто скроллить вниз-вверх), то чувствуются лаги при загрузке и показе рекламы (после показа лаги проходят). Пробовал отложенно подгружать в активность огромные картинки, при их появлении в активности нет и намёка на лаги. И ещё: лагов нет в старых Андроидах, я думаю что это связано с тем, что новые Андроиды отключают ускорение, а Вы как раз разъяснили, как его включить.

Comment: Всё ещё лагает, но вроде бы чуть-чуть поменьше. Сейчас подредактирую ответ, и его можно будет считать здравой рекомендацией всем ищущим.